# C# HttpResonseMessage works in Consoleprogram but not in Forms or WPF with the same Code

Tags: httpclient, c#-5.0

i got a odd issue, when i try this code in C# Console Application than it runs and returns me a json.
But when I try this on WPF or Windows Form it doesnt do anything and stucks by

> await client.GetAsync(url);

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            var result = Test().Result;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        public static async Task<string> Test()
        {
            using var client = new HttpClient();

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.bitfinex.com/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "C# console program");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var url = "v1/pubticker/adausd";
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var resp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return resp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that is not working?

Comment: The Code above is not working in Forms and WPF but in Console, same Code..